# Randomly selecting attribute value in ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, oop, random, binary-tree

This is my Node class for creating nodes in my binary tree.

```
# This class creates node.
class Node
 attr_accessor :value,:left,:right,:random
 def initialize(value,left,right)
  @value = value
  @left = left
  @right = right 
  @random = ["left","right"].sample
  puts "\nNode with value #{@value} is created".green
 end
end
```

Below code is one of the lines of my binary tree creation code

```
current.left = Node.new(val,nil,nil)
```

But instead of using like `current.left` or `current.right` , i want to randomly select either `left` or `right`. Hence i tried to create random attribute `@random = ["left","right"].sample` and use it like `current.random = Node.new(val,nil,nil)`. But this doesn't work obviously. Can anyone guide me how to approach this.

Comment: i was using `gem colorize` to color text in console thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically set class attributes with [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-send)

```
prop_name = ["left","right"].sample
prop_value = Node.new(val,nil,nil)
current.send("#{prop_name}=",prop_value)
```

Or more simply

```
current.send("#{['left','right'].sample}=", Node.new(val,nil,nil))
```

Comment: cant i do like this ? `current.send("#{['left','right'].sample}") = Node.new(val,nil,nil)`

Comment: No.  You are calling a method on the current object, and the parameters you are passing in is what allows you to dynamically set the attributes.  You are not setting the attributes by directly calling the setters, but instead passing a function name (in this case a setter), arguments (in this case what you want to set your attribute to) and then allowing `send` to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

With this implementation a random number (either 0 or 1) will be stored, representing `left` and `right` respectively. You can also call `reset_random_method` to re-roll where the random method is pointing.

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :left, :right
  def initialize(value, left = nil, right = nil)
    self.value = value
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
    reset_random_method
  end

  def reset_random_method
    self.random_number = rand 2
  end

  def random
    send([:left, :right][random_number])
  end

  def random=(value)
    send([:left=, :right=][random_number], value)
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :random_number
end
```

Comment: I think this is the first time I've seen a private accessor. Nothing wrong with, just a bit unusual.

Comment: I generally make accessors private when I want them to keep a defined state (in this case either a 0 or 1 value). This way the user can interact with `random_number` in a safe manner (via `reset_random_method`) and not compromise the state either inadvertently or for malicious purposes.